# What is the directory “C:\Users\TEMP”?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, temporary-files

I would like to know what the purpose of the directory `C:\Users\TEMP` in Windows 7 is. I am installing Aptana from the Admin account and it is trying to place files there, specifically, in `C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Aptana`

Comment: I have Win7 and I don't have a C:\Users\TEMP directory. I don't think it's put there by windows. Perhaps it was Aptana that put it there.

Comment: did you mean c:\users\USERNAME\Temp?

Comment: There is no `C:\Users\Temp` folder, or at least there shouldn’t be unless you create a user named `Temp`. Unfortunately some programs are poorly written and put files in the wrong place (maybe a missing variable name or superfluous `..`, etc.) so it may have ended up in teh wrong place (though permissions *should* prevent that).

Comment: @uSlackr, even that would be an incorrect; it should have been put in `AppData\Local` (by default).

Comment: What else is in the directory?

Answer (score 13):

`C:\Users\Temp` means that a user has been logged on with a temporary profile. Generally, this means the user's real profile is missing or corrupted.

You can determine whether the folder contains a profile by examining its contents. If you see directories named Desktop, Documents (or My Documents), Pictures, etc., then it is a profile directory.

Given that Aptana wants to put files there while you are logged in as the Administrator, and the fact that `C:\Users\Temp` is usually deleted when the affected user logs off, my hunch is that the current user, Administrator, is logged on with the temporary profile. You can check this by opening a command prompt and typing `set userprof`. You should get a list of environment variables that includes `USERPROFILE`. If this value is set to `C:\Users\Temp`, it is indeed the current user who is afflicted.

Comment: If a user’s profile is corrupt or there is not enough disk space, a “temporary” profile may indeed be created by copying the default-user profile. It may vary, but I have never seen it be created as `C:\Users\Temp`, but rather as something like `C:\Users\<computername>.<username>`, or something with the username in it.

Comment: I created a new user, logged in an out, and moved the profile folder. When I logged back in, the temporary profile folder was indeed C:\Users\Temp.

Comment: Really? That’s odd, XP’s method of using the username in the folder makes much more sense. Then again, a lot of Vista+’s changes have been poor.

Comment: I think if you have a user named Temp, and they get a temporary profile, the computer explodes.

Comment: In my case, comodo firewall is catching an edit from dllhost.exe to firefox, and if i dont allow it it wont let me delete the `TEMP` dir (maybe other reasons, since its a downgraded admin user), however that to me is pretty fishy.  The only thing in there is a roaming FF `prefs.js` and `search.json.mozlz4` .  Im not big in introducing more problems, somehow these prefs are tied in it appears.

Answer (score 4):

Look at what's in the directory.  If you aren't familiar with it, compress the directory using 7zip and rename the whole thing (to back it up).  Then delete the original directory.  If nothing happens, run with it for a while.  When YOU are convinced that the directory had no value, delete the backup you made with 7zip.

If you compress and rename the backup you create, and all heck breaks loose, reboot Windows in safe mode, and put everything back like it was.

This will help you determine if it is needed, and if not, helps you safely get rid of it.

ANY program could have made that TEMP directory.

Comment: Thank you. I came here because I was asking a similar question here: https://superuser.com/posts/1621227/edit

Comment: Glad to be of service, hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Profiles Wont Load. Stuck with Backup Status.

There are bugs that you can get around with, and then there are some that are just weird.. I came across one that involved a weird state for a local windows profile. Usually this will prompt you to simply solve the issue by just re-creating the profile. This usually solves the issue, but there is a faster way to resolve issues that involve with the profile with a backup status:Image

The image above doesn't really show a backup status, but you get the picture. The profile in question will load the home directory `c:\users\TEMP`. The user's desktop won't be the same, outlook won't have the same profile, and the user's favorites will be gone. Let's not panic, the folder in question is still there. The user is just not properly mapped to the right home directory.

First thing to do is to reboot the workstation in question. If you still have the same issue, we will need to modify the registry.

NOTE: Modifying the registry is risky, and even if you follow the instructions word for word, I can't guarantee success or a corrupted windows or loss of data. Please proceed at your own risk.

This remedy is taken from this Microsoft KB article, but ill mention it here for completeness and add my thoughts to each task.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

Go to Start and run REGEDIT

Go to:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
In this key, you should see something similar to this:
Image
The S-1-5-21 keys actually are the configuration of the profiles in windows. one thing to notice is that there are two that are strikingly similar (S-1-5-21-1079119....) but with one difference, the .bak at the end of the key at the bottom.

Lets take a look inside the key:

A healthy profile should look like this:

Image

A cool thing to note is that the ProfileImagePath points to the home directory of the user. An unhealthy profile will display the ProfileImagePath to `c:\users\temp`, and the RefCount will have a value higher than 0.

To solve the problem, login to an administrator account other than the one that has the issue.

Next modify the key name that doesn't have the .bak to .ba.

Image

Now Rename the key that HAS the .bak and remove the .bak.

Image

Finally modify the key name that HAS the .ba to .bak

Image

Once that is done, you will need to modify a few more things in the key without the .bak.

We need to change the RefCount to 0

We need to clear the state in State to 0

Now its time to reboot and try to login.

This worked for me. What your more or less doing is manually changing the state of the profile from the backup state to a local state

PROPS to [Tmatthews](http://microitblog.com/micro-it-blog/2012/01/17/windows-7-profiles-wont-load-stuck-with-backup-status)

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/user-profile-status-set-to-backup/3b665aa4-3c49-4e65-9fe1-446e61f39c19)

Comment: So how does that answer the question, exactly?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).