# Safely and completely remove any unwanted TEMP or other users in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, users

In `C:\Users` folder I have three unwanted user folders that do not appear in `Profiles` in `Advanced System Settings` or in users in general (check `Notes` below).

**A little Background**
Setting up a new win10 system, I logged in with a user i.e. `jonDoe@hotmail.com`, but Win10 automatically made the path something like this `C:\Users\jond` which I didn't like and I attempted to change it based [on this guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/how-to-change-username-on-pc-located-in-cusers-in/ed70f119-0dd3-422f-a3f9-6dcff3a2bcad). But probably because I forgot to disable OneDrive, after the first restart I could not sign in with `jonDoe@hotmail.com` as win10 had taken the extra step to sign me with a temporary account.
I corrected the issue by creating a second admin profile with which I was able to fix the first one. However, then I saw that there was, as expected, a `jon` folder and the 2nd admin folder (let's call it `mary`), two temporary user folders and the initial folder called `jond`. I thought that win10 would automatically delete the last three folders, but it didn't.

**Notes**
 1. Upon visiting `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` I see no `Temporary`, `.TEMP` or `jond` profile.
 2. Hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`, these Users **don't show up** in User Profiles either.

**Question**
How can I safely purge those unwanted folders and all the junk that follow these users?

**Warning**: The question doesn't point to `Public` or `Default` Users. It may break your windows if you do so.
***Note, based on selected answer:*** In the case that the user folder cannot get deleted because `another program is currently using this file`, then go to Safe Mode and delete it (take a backup first, or even better create a Restore Point!).*

Comment: What profiles are you specifically worried about.  You should [edit[ your question instead of submitting any additional commentary.

Comment: @Ramhound, Sometimes it is difficult to conceive if the question can be understood from others, not until if someone comes and comments that he didn't understand. I had `edited` my question after John's reply (you can see the history) but it seems it was not enough for you or others. So I took the step to amend it again for future users. Please let me know if it is better now. If you have suggestions or want to be constructive it would be nice.

Comment: As a bit of self-replying, I also found this answer, similar to John's answer below. Backup should be taken first before deleting any folder. 
https://superuser.com/a/452693/196765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, log in with the proper User Name (Account) and make very certain you have logged in to your own account and not a temporary account.

Do not worry excessively about Windows choice of your User Profile name. It will work fine.

**Deleting User Profiles in Advanced Settings:**

Then from your own Account, Start, Settings, About. Scroll down the right hand side and select "Advanced System Settings"

In Advanced System Settings, select the Advanced Tab and click on the User Profile Settings.

Delete whatever profiles you set up and do not need.

If need be, set up a brand new account to keep, log into that and clean up old accounts.

**Deleting Temporary or other User folders in Explorer:**

In that new account, and making sure no excess Profiles, you can use Windows Explorer to delete old profiles in USERS.

Open Windows Explorer in an Admin Account that is not one of the USER Profiles you wish to delete. Navigate down to USERS and delete the Profiles you wish. You will need to OK UAC on deletion most likely.

It is safe to delete USER folders that are no longer in use (the Accounts are not used.)

..

[image]

Comment: Sorry John, but I indicated that these users are not shown up there. (The line before the last one)

Comment: @YannisDran - While you did indeed say it, what you say was **extremely confusing**, and until you this answer even I wouldn't have known what you were trying to say,

Comment: You said you had John and Mary accounts and if things are that badly set up, make a brand new, known good Profile and use that to clean up others.  You can also use Windows Explorer to clean up old folders in USERS.  I have amended my answer to include this.

Comment: @John, thank you. So, I assume that just deleting those folders with a simple "Delete" is enough? By the way, I edited the question again to make it even more clear.

Comment: Yes, you can delete USERS folders that are no longer needed.  E.G. If you need Joe but do not need Mary, delete Mary.

Comment: Yes thank you. I only temporarily made `mary`, so it will get deleted too, but as her folder won't remain as other folders did, it didn't trouble me. I would follow your answer's steps for that `mary` folder. -- Please, if you like, amend your answer a bit so it is clear that it is safe to delete these folders, so other users will know exactly what it is asked and answered. Maybe put that last paragraph first? Then I will select your answer as the one which solved the problem. Cheers

Comment: Good point and I have made that change.

Comment: I have also done some formatting to clarify two approaches.  I trust this helps.